# Selecting max value from joined table in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two tables: `dbo.Projects` and `dbo.Buffers`. `dbo.Projects` has many `dbo.buffers`.

I need to select various columns from `dbo.Projects`, and the `MAX(PercentConsumed)` row from `dbo.Buffers`, but I can't seem to figure it out. It seems that SQL server 2008 isn't allowing me to get that max value.

Here's what I have thus far:

```
SELECT 
P.ProjectName, P.ProjectManager, P.PlannedStart, MAX(B.PercentConsumed) AS 'PercentConsumed'
FROM dbo.Projects AS P
LEFT JOIN dbo.Buffers AS B ON P.ProjectID = B.ProjectID
GROUP BY P.ProjectName
HAVING P.ProjectType = 8 AND P.Category 23;
```

The results are giving me multiple rows of the same project, whereas I simply want the max value from `B.PercentConsumed`

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Use a sub select, example: Select max(COLUMN) from (YOUR SELECT) AS TBL

Comment: It seems to be just giving me the highest value from the table for every row

Comment: Does Buffers have a Unique ID column?

Comment: something is missing from your code example.. pretty sure `P.ProjectManager` and  `P.PlannedStart` would have to be in your group by if this is sql server

Comment: Is ProjectName unique?
You say you want the row with the higher PercentConsumed but you are only selecting Max(PercentConsumed). Please clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query should be giving you an error.

You need to Group By all the non-aggregated columns:

```
SELECT 
P.ProjectName, P.ProjectManager, P.PlannedStart, MAX(B.PercentConsumed) AS 'PercentConsumed'
FROM dbo.Projects AS P
LEFT JOIN dbo.Buffers AS B ON P.ProjectID = B.ProjectID
WHERE P.ProjectType = 8 AND P.Category 23
GROUP BY P.ProjectName, P.ProjectManager, P.PlannedStart
;
```